# Variance Dissimilarity in SQL with three table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three table:

1. rtgitems

   [image: rtgitems]
2. rtgusers

   [image: rtgusers]
3. POI

   [image: POI]

(the tables aren't complete for reasons of space).

I want to resolve this form:

[image: vd]

where r_i,x is the value of column "voto" for the user "rater" i for the "item" x and avg_x is the average (the division from "totalrate" and "nrrates" -> totalrate/nrrates). |G| is given and isn't a trouble.

I want this table result:

```
Nome (from POI) | VD_x(G)
Tour Eiffel     | 23
Arc             | 18
...
```

I tried this for the firsts two table for to take the value for calculate the average (the third table I don't know how matching with the others):

```
 SELECT totalrate, nrrates, voto FROM rtgitems INNER JOIN rtgusers ON    rtgitems.item=rtgusers.item GROUP BY rater
```

but don't work.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "*don't work*" is not very informative.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: You will get mysterious results (most of the time) if you don't have a "full" group by, that is a group by with all columns in the select clause that is not part of an aggregate (such as count). SQL92 dictates that this must be the case, SQL99 loosens this restriction and says something like "all columns in the select clause must be functionally dependent of the group by clause. All DBMS that I know of kept the more restrictive implementation. MySQL on the other hand ignores this completely by default (can be changed by adding ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to @@sql_mode).

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem you face, but be careful with how you use group by. As a silly example, what is the result of: `insert into T (x,y) values (1,1),(1,2); select x,y from T group by x`, is it (1,1) or (1,2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just focus on the `rtgusers` table.  If you want to bring in the names, that's fine.  You can do it after the variance calculation (you seem to know what a `join` is).  The first table seems superfluous to the problem.

You can calculate the variance by pre-calculating the summary values and then applying the formula.  I think this is the basic logic that you want:

```
SELECT ru.item, (1.0 / max(rus.n)) * sum(power(ru.voto - avg_voto), 2)
FROM rtgusers ru join
     (select ru.item, avg(voto * 1.0) as avg_voto, count(*) as n
      from rtgusers ru
      group by ru.item
     ) rus
     on ru.item = rus.item
group by ru.item;
```